# Binary Search Tree C implementation

Tags: c, binary-search-tree

I recently wrote a fairly simple piece of code attempting to implement a Binary Search Tree in C with insertion, search, deletion and display operations. Unfortunately, the code does not seem to work.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

struct TreeNode {
    int data;
    struct TreeNode *leftChildNode;
    struct TreeNode *rightChildNode;
};

typedef struct TreeNode node;
node *rootNode = NULL;

void insertNode(int i, node *n) {
    if(n == NULL) {
        n = (node*)malloc(sizeof(node));
        n->leftChildNode = NULL;
        n->rightChildNode = NULL;
        n->data = i;
    }
    else 
    if(n->data == i)
        printf("\nThis value already exists in the tree!");
    else
    if(i > n->data)
        insertNode(i, n->rightChildNode);
    else
        insertNode(i, n->leftChildNode);
    }

void searchNode(int i, node *n) {
    if(n == NULL)
        printf("\nValue does not exist in tree!");
    else
    if(n->data == i)
        printf("\nValue found!");
    else
    if(i > n->data)
        searchNode(i, n->rightChildNode);
    else
        searchNode(i, n->leftChildNode);
    }

void deleteNode(int i, node *n) {
    if(n == NULL)
        printf("\nValue does not exist in tree!");
    else
    if(n->data == i) {
        if(n->leftChildNode == NULL)
            n = n->rightChildNode;
        else
        if(n->rightChildNode == NULL)
            n = n->leftChildNode;
        else {
            node *temp = n->rightChildNode;
            while(temp->leftChildNode != NULL)
                temp = temp->leftChildNode;
            n = temp;
        }
    }
    else
    if(i > n->data)
        deleteNode(i, n->rightChildNode);
    else
        deleteNode(i, n->leftChildNode);
    }

void displayPreOrder(node *n) {
    if(n != NULL) {
        printf("%d ", n->data);
        displayPreOrder(n->leftChildNode);
        displayPreOrder(n->rightChildNode);
    }
}

void displayPostOrder(node *n) {
    if(n != NULL) {
        displayPostOrder(n->leftChildNode);
        displayPostOrder(n->rightChildNode);
        printf("%d ", n->data);
    }
}

void displayInOrder(node *n) {
    if(n != NULL) {
        displayInOrder(n->leftChildNode);
        printf("%d ", n->data);
        displayInOrder(n->rightChildNode);
    }
}

int main(void) {
    int ch, num, num1;
    do {
        printf("\nSelect a choice from the menu below.");
        printf("\n1. Insert a node.");
        printf("\n2. Search for a node.");
        printf("\n3. Delete a node.");
        printf("\n4. Display the Binary Search Tree.");
        printf("\nChoice: ");
        scanf("%d", &ch);
        switch(ch) {
            case 1: printf("\nEnter an element: ");
                    scanf("%d", &num);
                    //printf("YESYES");
                    insertNode(num, rootNode);
                    break;

            case 2: printf("\nEnter the element to be searched for: ");
                    scanf("%d", &num);
                    searchNode(num, rootNode);
                    break;

            case 3: printf("\nEnter the element to be deleted: ");
                    scanf("%d", &num);
                    deleteNode(num, rootNode);
                    break;

            case 4: printf("\nSelect an order for the elements to be display in.");
                    printf("\n1. Pre-order.");
                    printf("\n2. Post-order.");
                    printf("\n3. In-order.");
                    printf("\nChoice: ");
                    scanf("%d", &num1);
                    switch(num1) {
                        case 1: printf("\nPre-order Display: ");
                                displayPreOrder(rootNode);
                                break;

                        case 2: printf("\nPost-order Display: ");
                                displayPostOrder(rootNode);
                                break;

                        case 3: printf("\nIn-order Display: ");
                                displayInOrder(rootNode);
                                break;

                        default: exit(0);
                    }
                    break;

            default: exit(0);
            }
        //printf("%d", rootNode->data);
        printf("\nIf you want to return to the menu, press 1.");
        printf("\nChoice: ");
        scanf("%d", &num);
    } while(num == 1);

    return 0;
}
```

In fact, notice the commented line `printf("%d", rootNode->data);` just before the `do-while` block in `main()` ends. If I uncomment this line, compile the program and run it, the program throws a segmentation fault. Could anyone tell me why this error is occurring and why the code as a whole isn't running? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 5):

You have a misconception about the way C handles arguments. In C, all arguments are passed by value, including pointers. When you reassign a pointer inside of a function you are reassigning a copy of that pointer.

For instance:

```
void f ( int *p );

int *p;

f(p);
```

The address (`&p`) of the pointer is different in the function. They both point to the same location (have **the same value**), but each has **a different address**. When you assign the pointer to the return value of `malloc`, it is only assigning the function local copy of that pointer.

One way to fix this is to introduce another level of indirection, and pass the address of the pointer: `void insertNode(int i, node **n)`, which you can call like `insertNode(0, &n)`. When you want to change it to something else, dereference it once and *then* assign: `*p = malloc(sizeof(node))`.

Another solution is to have the function return the pointer and assign it in the calling code: `return malloc(sizeof(node))`. (Note: You would actually return it after the initialization code... also don't cast the return value of `malloc` in C).

Answer (score 1):

At the top, you declare

```
node *rootNode = NULL;
```

If you don't run `insertNode` (successfully - See Matt's answer), the node will still be NULL when trying to print it and that's why you're getting the segfault.

Comment: Why the downvote? I realize this is not the complete answer, but OP did also ask for why his code segfaults when trying to print.

Answer (score 1):

The reason why the code segfaults when you uncomment the printf statement is because rootNode is a NULL pointer. Dereferencing this NULL pointer in the function call causes the segfault.

The reason that rootNode is a NULL pointer is that it is never changed by the code. Calling `insertNode()`  results in the local variable `n` being set to the value that is stored in `rootNode` (in this case NULL). The changes to `n` in the `insertNode()` function do not change `rootNode`.

To fix the code you could change the `insertNode` and `deleteNode` functions to accept a pointer to the root node pointer. For example the `insertCode()` function would become:

```
void insertNode(int i, node **n) {
    if(*n == NULL) {
        (*n) = (node*)malloc(sizeof(node));
        (*n)->leftChildNode = NULL;
        (*n)->rightChildNode = NULL;
        (*n)->data = i;
    }
    else
    {
        if((*n)->data == i)
        {
            printf("\nThis value already exists in the tree!");
        }
        else
        {
            if(i > (*n)->data)
                insertNode(i, &(*n)->rightChildNode);
            else
                insertNode(i, &(*n)->leftChildNode);
        }
    }
}
```

You would also have to change the code to call `insertNode()` with a reference to rootNode `insertNode(num, &rootNode);`

I also recommend that you check the return values of the various scanf calls. If `scanf("%d",x)` returns 0 then the value not be converted to an int and the contents of x are undefined. Ideally the code would handle this case gracefully.

Answer (score 0):

I think the probblem is with the signature for Insert function Try the below code and It will work

```
void insertNode(int i, node **n) {
    if(*n == NULL) {
        *n = (node*)malloc(sizeof(node));
        (*n)->leftChildNode = NULL;
        (*n)->rightChildNode = NULL;
        (*n)->data = i;
    }
    else 
    if((*n)->data == i)
        printf("\nThis value already exists in the tree!");
    else
    if(i > (*n)->data)
        insertNode(i, &((*n)->rightChildNode));
    else
        insertNode(i, &((*n)->leftChildNode));
    }
```

And use Insert Function as

```
insertNode(num, &rootNode);
```

Earlier the changes remain in the function  Insert only. Use double pointer inside.